# My regex is not working

Tags: regex

I have a excel file that must have this name format, where xxx is a number, Curr is either EUR or GBP and yymmdd is a date.

```
CDFSDDRCxxxCurryymmdd.xls(x)
```

And this is the regex I'm using. It doesn´t works with dates like 120920 or 121005.
Any Ideas??

```
Match nameIsValid = Regex.Match(activeWorkbook.Name,
                                      @"CDFSDDRC(?<xxx>\d+)(?<curr>EUR|GBP)(?<yymmdd>\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[12])(?:(?:0|1|2)[1-9]|3[0-2]))\.xls?");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix for this regex would be the following one:

```
CDFSDDRC(?<xxx>\d+)(?<curr>EUR|GBP)(?<yymmdd>\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[012])(?:(?:0|1|2)[0-9]|3[0-2]))\.xls?
```

You can check out the results **[here](http://regexr.com?3231i)**.

Note that this one will match if the day of the month is `00`.

My opinion is that you should not be checking for a valid days, months and years in your regex. You can match a 6-digit date by using the following, much simpler regex:

```
CDFSDDRC(?<xxx>\d+)(?<curr>EUR|GBP)(?<yymmdd>\d{6})\.xls?
```

After you match it, you can then programmatically check whether it's a valid date or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit simpler than what you had

```
"CDFSDDRC(\d+)(EUR|GBP)(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}).xls"
```